# ASP.Net Updatepanel Placement

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a page with 3 fields on it. An amount (textbox), a payment terms (dropdown) (once, montly, quarterly, etc.) and an amount to be charged based on what is selected in the dropdown. The dropdown is set to autopostback=true. The operation works to calculate the amount to be charged, but pops back to the top of the page during postback. I know I need an updatepanel to do a partial postback, I just can't figure out how to code it or where to put it in my code. The attempts I have made seem to swallow the postback, and nothing happens.

This is the code without the updatepanel:

```
<div class="row form-group">

    <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="lblTotal">Total Amount:<asp:textbox ID="lblTotal" runat="server" visible="true" borderstyle="None" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" BackColor="#FFFFFF"/></label>

   <div class="col-md-3 "><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" id="lblDollar" style="border-color:#4B116F; border-width:2px; color:#4B116F;">$</span>

   <asp:textbox ID="lblTotalAmount" Runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ReadOnly="false" class="form-control" aria-describedby="lblDollar" style="border-color:#4B116F; border-width:2px; color:#4B116F;" AutoPostBack="false"/></div></div>

   <div class="col-md-3"><asp:rangeValidator id="rvalTotalAmount" ControlToValidate="lblTotalAmount" runat="server" type="Double" Minimumvalue="5.00" Maximumvalue="30000.00" ErrorMessage="For your security we limit online gifts to a range of $5.00 to $30,000.00."  Text="*"></asp:rangeValidator><asp:CustomValidator ID="cvalDesignation" runat="server" errormessage="Please enter a designation."  Text="*"/></div>

</div>

<div class="row form-group">

<label class="control-label col-md-4">Payment Terms: </label>
<div class="col-md-3">
    
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCCFrequency" Runat="server" class="ddl_styler_combo ddl-size dropdown-toggle" AutoPostBack="true" style="border-radius:4px; width:160px;"/>

</div>

<asp:TextBox ID="tbxAuthNetAmt" runat="server" visible="true" borderstyle="solid" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" BackColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</div>

<div class="row form-group">

<label class="control-label col-md-4">Card will be charged: </label>

<div class="col-md-3"><div class="input-group">

<span class="input-group-addon ddl_styler_combo" id="ccDollar" style="border-color:#4B116F; border-width:2px; color:#4B116F; font-weight:bold; height:33px;">$</span>

<asp:TextBox ID="tbxCardAmount" readonly="false" Runat="server" class="form-control ddl_styler_combo ddl-size" aria-describedby="ccDollar"  style="border-color:#4B116F; border-width:2px; color:#4B116F; border-bottom-right-radius:4px; border-top-right-radius:4px;" />

</div></div>
<div class="col-md-2"><asp:CustomValidator id="cvalCardChargeSchedule" runat="server" enabled="true" ErrorMessage="Please specify a billing schedule" /></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> "The attempts I have made seem to swallow the postback"

**when this is happens its means that you have JavaScript errors.**

From this code only the validator's can cause JavaScript errors - Remove them temporary to see if `UpdatePanel` working, and then add one by one to locate what is going wrong.

Alternative see for javacript errors as you have the page using the Web Browser Tools.